# How to convert images to WEBP before sending them to Firebase using React-dropzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-storage, webp, react-dropzone

For `performance`, I need to reduce the size of the images I send to my `cloud storage (firebase)`. Through some research I came to know `webp` is the way to go but I'm using `react dropzone` and I have to idea how to work these 2 together.

DragAndDrop.js

```
function DragAndDrop() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: "image/*",
    maxFiles: 5,
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
      setFiles((files) => [
        ...files,
        ...acceptedFiles.map((file) =>
          Object.assign(file, {
            key: file.name + randomId(), // to allow adding files with same name
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
          })
        ),
      ]);
    },
  });
 
  const thumbs = files.map((file, i) => (
    <div style={thumb} key={file.key}>
      <div style={thumbInner}>
        <img src={file.preview} style={img} alt="imported images" />
      </div>
      <button type="button" style={removeButton} onClick={() => removeFile(i)}>
        X
      </button>
    </div>
  ));

  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      files.forEach((file) => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
    },
    [files]
  );

}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (which I very well may be) [react-dropzone doesn't have any tools for compression on purpose](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/438#issuecomment-307031166), but I think that the place where you'd perform the compression would be either in the [`onDrop`](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#:~:text=Cb%20for%20when%20the%20drop%20event%20occurs) function or on `onDropAccepted`. Am I right to assume that by webp you're referring to the npm library [imagemin-webp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-webp)?

Comment: I didn't know about `imagemin-webp` but I knew was that using the picture tag you could use webp format. Do you have any idea on how to perform the compression ?

Comment: From what I can read from the library page I linked in combination with how the onDrop function: within the onDrop function you'd compress the image received and then replace the image in the onDrop process with your compressed version. Compressing is done with the `imagemin` function, just make sure to include the plugin as per the library page.

Comment: From the moment I installed imagemin i'm getting this error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
Did you mean './fs'? Do you know an alternative to imagemin ?

Comment: Missing `fs`? I'm pretty sure that means it's expecting to be in a node.js server, I don't know of any alternative to imagemin, at least not on JS (that I can think of at the moment). Apologies for the delayed repsonse. Quick Google Search lead me to [this webpage](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/image-compression-in-reactjs-a07ec0066b24) leading me to the [compressorjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-js) library, and it seems to be a bit more detailed in its description than imagemin - not sure if you'd prefer it though.

Comment: Also, I've only caught wind of this recently, but if you have a Blaze account for Firebase, then you can use the [`Firebase Resize Image`](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-storage-resize-images) extension